# Single or small number of words opposite of "soft focus", "rose-tinted glasses" etc to convey cynicism/critical thinking/realism but not "pessimistic"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms

I'm looking for a single word or small number of words to convey something like "Life through a _____ filter/lens" where the opposite is 'soft-focus', 'rose-tinted' etc.

Where _____ conveys a sense of gritty realism, critical thinking or getting to the root or 'principle' of things, but not necessarily being "pessimistic".

For example when you take a photo using a "soft focus" technique it blurs out a lot of the details, can hide unfortunate features in the original picture, etc.

I did check this [possibly related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174738/pessimism-idiom-opposite-of-rose-tinted-glasses) and I love the idea of looking at the world through "half-empty glasses"! - but that question is about being pessimistic rather than 'just' realistic or thinking critically etc. I'm not looking through "half-empty glasses"; I'm looking through glasses that don't actually change the view in any way, but realising the nature of what I'm actually looking at.

Comment: Maybe you want "Unfiltered".  An unfiltered look at...

Comment: How about "scientific"?

Answer (score 1):

**Clear-eyed** means:

```
having a shrewd understanding and no illusions.
"clear-eyed about human nature"
```

from Google

And a sample sentence from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/clear-eyed)

> In the way they approach engineering, they have learnt to put emotions to one side and to look in a clear-eyed way at the evidence.

You could say "clear-eyed lens" if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is **hard-boiled** (usually applied to eggs) but also used to describe a wordly-wise character with a cynical outlook. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard-boiled) has

> **1** *of an egg* : boiled until both white and yolk have solidified
>
> **2 a** : devoid of sentimentality: tough
>   *a hard-boiled drill sergeant*
>
> **2 b** : of, relating to, or being a detective story featuring a tough unsentimental protagonist and a matter-of-fact attitude towards violence
>
> **3** : hardheaded, practical
>   *hard-boiled business decisions*

Answer (score 0):

How about "skeptical" ("sceptical" in the UK)? Looking at "skeptical" in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skepticism), this might work rather well:

> skepticism noun
>   skep·​ti·​cism | \ ˈskep-tə-ˌsi-zəm   \
>
> Definition of skepticism
>
> 1 : an attitude of doubt or a disposition to incredulity either in general or toward a particular object
>
> 2a : the doctrine that true knowledge or knowledge in a particular area is uncertain
>
> b : the method of suspended judgment, systematic doubt, or criticism characteristic of skeptics
>
> 3 : doubt concerning basic religious principles (such as immortality, providence, and revelation)

Answer (score 0):

An unsentimental appraisal that is unblinking, determined, cool-headed and steely could be described as ***unflinching***.

'***Flinch***' - To draw back through failure in courage, endurance, or resolve; to shrink from something as dangerous, painful, or difficult (OED).